# Pretty much vs basically

Tags: adverbs, synonyms, adverbial-phrases

Can ***"Pretty much"*** and ***"basically"*** be used interchangeably and mean the same thing?

For example,

> I'm pretty much done.

VS

> I'm basically done.

Another example:

> Polar bears are basically extinct.

VS

> polar bears are pretty much extinct

Comment: "I'm pretty much done" versus "I'm basically done" are fine and basically mean pretty much the same thing.

Comment: "Polar bears are basically extinct" and "Polar bears are pretty much extinct" are also pretty much, basically the same thing, but not many people would say it this way because it makes us sound like we are apathetic to the plight of polar bears. We would probably say, "Polar bears are almost extinct" or "Polar bears are nearly extinct."

Answer (score 1):

The meanings of the two phrases are the same, but they are different with regards to formality. *Pretty much* is more informal than *basically*. I would only use *pretty much* in conversational contexts, but *basically* I would use in both conversational contexts and more formal ones.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know. To me, pretty much and basically are basically pretty informal for me. I feel like a more "formal" alternative would be, "almost" or "nearly."

Comment: In my opinion, *almost* and *nearly* are very slightly different in terms of when I'd use them. It's hard to quantify, but I would use *almost* or *nearly* to describe a task that's something like 95% done, whereas I'd use *pretty much* or *basically* at something closer to 99% done. It's a very fine distinction but I know personally there's a difference between how I'd use each set of terms.

Comment: Hmmm, I see....